# Which U.S. political party should one join in order to reorganize the government into a dictatorial autocracy?

Tags: government, futurology, politics

In the near future (2035), a power-hungry individual plans to become a politician, climb the ladder of power, be elected President of the United States of America, and then reorganize the government into a dictatorial autocracy.

Given the political system of the United States:

- What path would a person with republican tendencies and affiliation to the party take to achieve dictatorial powers?
- What path would a person with democratic (the party) tendencies and affiliation to the party take to achieve dictatorial powers?

Is either party more likely to support the rise of a person/power like this?

Answers should be based on current and future political, social and technological trends.

Comment: Hello user 50726! Your question is a little unclear -- you may want to [edit] in why you think one party might have a dictatorial advantage over the other. If you have a specific question about how the two-party political system works in the US, you might want to ask it at http://politics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Shokhet : I don't think he will get an answer there. Since it's about the future I think it's on topic here. The problem is that it's really speculative.

Comment: @Vincent I agree. I don't think 50476 should ask this exact question over there, but if he's thinking about one specific ideology of either party, asking over there might help with whatever's bothering him/her.

Comment: We can't answer this question because it is entirely subjective, which means you can basically choose whatever you want. Parties also change, which means we can't predict what they will be like in the future.

Comment: it's not off topic, it's opinion based.

Comment: The political system is not static.  The position of the political parties is not set in stone, they're always changing slowly.  There is no way we could make any statements about what the Dems. or Reps. would be like in 100 years, so the only valid responses would be based on the current political stances. If the question is based on the current political stances, then Shokhet is absolutely correct that it belongs on politics.stackexchange.com instead of here. @User50746: if you would like this answered here, can you describe the platforms you believe those two parties will hold in 100 years?

Comment: @CortAmmon, 2035 isn't exactly 100 years away. And twenty years isn't all that far away to speculate about; its possible that not all that much will change over that short of a timescale. But there is still no objective way to answer this question, unless the OP defines what his politician's goals and beliefs are?

Comment: Wow... you are absolutely right.  Apparently math is optional in my brain tonight, and subtraction of two years is not working as well as it should!

Comment: This doesn't seem off-topic to me at all. It asks about the most plausible path by which one could get from the world at present to a particular hypothetical future. There are meaningful differences between the two major US parties in terms of their major donors, their geographic distribution of support, their history, and the beliefs and behaviors of their voters... so it seems absurd to say that the party is irrelevant. On the other hand, I grant that it also reads like a flamewar waiting to happen.

Comment: I'm with Vincent and octern.  This is on-topic, but the problem is that all answers will be opinion-based.  It doesn't fit the Q&A format well.  My answer would be to start his own party.  Note that the National Socialist German Workers Party was started in 1920 (or 1917) and gave rise to a dictatorship after 1933.  So I might suggest founding the Constitutional American Workers Party.  Of course, the US system is a bit different from the German political system of the 1920s.

Comment: This question does appear to be answerable. Assuming the parties current state and ideology (which has remained largely similar for the last 20 years). I'm going to edit for clarity...

Comment: Edited for clarity. Is this a better fit? I still think the people at politics would be better qualified to answer this.

Comment: Basically the above, I don't think this is a good fit for worldbuilding. It might be on-topic, but it is definitely opinion-based. No one will say their favorite party is the one that is more dictator-friendly. Honestly, I think someone wouldn't get very far in either party, the system is set up to prevent dictatorships.

Comment: @DonyorM you realize that could be an answer to the question right? :)

Comment: Suggestion: Perhaps a (slightly) better question might be something along the lines of "How might a US President become a dictator?" Granted, its still politically charged, but you can avoid implicating one party or the other, and instead look at identifying what obstacles in the current political system would need to be overcome (and how that might be done).

Comment: how does the political system of the US is preventing dictatorship ? (or why it can't become a tyranny like the UK lol). Probably belongs more in the Politic SE. I guess it depends on how the question is presented.

Comment: I took a crack at editing the question.  OP if I have mis-read your intentions and skewed the question from what you were trying to accomplish please let me know.

Comment: @James I know the comment could be an answer, but I didn't want to spend the time to develop it.

Answer (score 12):

Whichever one suits his ideology. Neither side is necessarily pro-dictatorship... unless you ask their opponents.

EDIT: You may find the [Nolan Chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nolan_Chart) to provide an interesting (if vastly oversimplified) perspective on U.S. party politics. It places Libertarian vs. Totalitarian (or Statist, or Populist, or Communitarian) as an orthogonal axis to left-wing/right-wing political parties.

Comment: Best answer to an off-topic question, I think.

Answer (score 7):

The political party is irrelevant because they are similar. The personality of the leader is the most important factor.

Comment: I'd suggest an edit as : The political party is irrelevant because they are the same. The personality of the leader is the most important factor.  ;)

Answer (score 3):

I'm glad the bits mentioning specific political parties were edited out, because I was worried that a lot of people would get offended by it (perhaps some were). More importantly, though, it means I don't have to address it in my answer. Well, you still do mention the parties, but there's a way around that.

Here's how to become dictator of the United States:

1. **Run for mayor of a moderately-sized town.** "Moderately-sized" means that the population is greater than say, 15,000 people while being less than, say, 50,000 people. (I'm putting the odds against you here, forcing you to rise from obscurity.) As mayor, you'll be the face of the town. People will know you, and you can gain popularity if you play your cards right.
2. **Become a member of the state legislature.** Here, you can make decisions that affect millions of people. Learn to work for the interests of many different, diverse groups, and gain their favor. Do what they want now so they'll trust you in the long run.
3. **Secure a state-level position.** You need to become the face (or one of the faces) of your state to the nation. There are two paths here:

   A. **Governor:** Get yourself elected to the top job in the state. You'll get some experience for running for president, if you choose to do so. Be prepared to veto a lot of bills.

   B. **Senator or Representative to Congress:** Here, you're taking the [Palpatine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palpatine) route. Fight for bills that benefit *your* home state, while being gracious to the nation. Again, make people like you, and make your home state love you. Forge alliances across the nation with other members of Congress, on both sides of the aisle.
4. **Run for president:** Here, we depart from the Palpatine route. If you were governor, you have experience with the duties of the executive branch. Either way, make sure that *as many people as possible* like you. Build their trust in you.
5. **Seize power:** Here, you need the help of others. If you were in Congress, you've got connections. Nudge bills into existence that give you more power. Bribe officials, especially members of Congress, to let you do things you're really not supposed to. Start a major war or two to help you unify the nation and make yourself look really good. Then, pass an innocuous-looking bill which contains a section, buried somewhere in the footnotes, that contains a loophole that lets you do whatever you want.

Comment: So this basically boils down to: (1-4.) Become a well-liked president. (5.) Bribe the legislators to pass a law that secretly makes you dictator. (6. Profit?)

Comment: @CalebHines Well, yes.

Comment: Sounds a bit like President Johnson, minus the part where his predecessor is mysteriously assassinated.

Comment: @SerbanTanasa Which one? LBJ and Andrew Johnson were both VPs when their predecessor was assassinated. Or did you intend that? :-)

Comment: Precisely my point. Something fishy about these Jonhsons :)

Answer (score 3):

The answer is simple.  There is no way for this to happen unless large blocs, even majorities of both parties agree on a unified policy of action due to some kind of major threat to the country as a whole.  And both sides would have to agree that President Dictator is the guy to solve this problem.

If a large part of any party disagreed, there are enough ways to slow down the process for the two terms of President Dictator to expire and send him on his way.  Note that part of the time would have to be spent actually trying to solve the problem, or else the idea that he is the guy for the job would start to be discredited.

The closest analog would be FDR. Enough people in the country liked his handling of the Depression and WWII that he was able to put in large changes in the government, like them or not without these changes being made into political targets for anyone except a small faction.

Answer (score 1):

In light of political events in America today, I thought it germane to resurrect this question.

It is strange how events that occur in just three years can drastically change the scope of a question from opinion-based to a question that has empirical evidence behind it.

I don't think anyone in 2014 could possibly have predicted the tremendous influence of social media, and in particular, Russian interference, on the American political scene. It is no longer a purely hypothetical scenario.

The answer has been proven to be 'Through intervention of public opinion through social media'. A concerted and directed dis-information campaign, directed by a centrally-organized body that has tremendous resources beyond just a political party (equivalent to the state resources of a country as powerful as Russia). A campaign that has access to an enormous data base of knowledge about the voting habits and, in fact, information on the personal habits and interests of the American public, hacked from sources as diverse as subscription lists and favorite internet sites visited. Then, using this database to specifically target social media messages to selected individuals, tailored to their fears and worries. See for instance [Data of almost 200 million voters leaked online by GOP analytics firm](http://money.cnn.com/2017/06/19/technology/voter-data-leaked-online-gop/index.html) as to how extensive this data base actually is.

In light of recent history, perhaps 2035 was overly pessimistic. But. in 2014, there were very few Americans who would ever have considered how much influence a foreign party could have on an American election. The internet, and social media, just wasn't considered a factor in any of the answers.

And in light of recent history, perhaps the door for using such techniques is rapidly closing.